# Debug embedded Jetty application in Eclipse

Tags: java, debugging, jetty, remote-debugging, embedded-jetty

I have a stand alone Java application with Embedded Jetty( It launches Jetty and prior setting Web context to a war file( which is a web service).
How do I debug this from my Eclipse. I can debug the application itself all right, up to the point that Jetty is launched, but after that the moment of Web Service invocation or even launching ?
Regards

Comment: I suppose it is straight forward thing but I am a bit confused by different tutorials

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to do? If you have an embedded jetty instance running inside of your application and you launch it from within Eclipse then there is no 'remote-debugging' going on.  If you are trying to connect up to a remote jvm within eclipse then that is pretty standard (and probably worth a page in our docs, will fix that).  If it is something else, please explain more what you are looking for in your original question...

Comment: I have a java standalone application, I run it from eclipse. The application launches Jetty , prior to lauch it sets it web context to a war file. ( which is a web service written by me) I would like to be in the position to step through the web service when it is invoked in debugger

Comment: You can't just do it now when running your application in Debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work for RestFul webservice created with multi module maven project
1. Go to Run > Debug Configurations
2. Choose Java Application, right click and click on new
3. Give any suitable name, 
4. In Main tab, for Project, give project name which contains your main method, Under Main Class, give class name which contains your main method
5. in Arguments, give your argument name like you provide from command line 
click on apply and press on debug button